UK visa - Past visa denial
I want to apply for a UK visa - Stage 2 of global talent fast route. However, in the part of the form where they ask to disclose past visa denials, I have a past denial from South Africa from a visa extension where the reason was "Incorrect Section" and "Incomplete Medical Form" (missed only the address, but it was stamped).
The outcome came 6 months after the expiry date from my initial visa. The only way to appeal was with a letter of good cause, for which I have the application certificate. The outcome came 4 months later, when I had already left and could only pick it up in person.
Is it wise to disclose this in this section? It makes sense to me, specially because VFS is involved in both visas.
How bad this would this affect my overall visa application? Everything else is good, including signed contract, endorsement, HR letter, etc...

It doesn't sound like a visa denial, but rather an extension of stay. I don't think it's the same

@littleadv In South Africa there is no such thing as an extension in this case (2 year visa). When my VISA expired I had to go through the entire process of requesting a new one.

Be on the safe side and disclose, doesn't sound really significant and omission can have much harsher ramifications than forgetting an address on a piece of paper

This sounds like a minor issue, so there is no reason to think it would have a significant effect on your application if you disclose it and explain the situation honestly. However, if you don't disclose it and are caught, the consequences are likely to be quite severe.

Thanks, I have disclosed and am hoping for the best.
